# What exactly is a member function?

Tags: python, function, class

I'm doing an assignment that says "*The class must also have member functions to perform the following tasks*"

When it says member functions does it mean something like:

```
class Example():

   def __init__(self,example):
      self.__example

   def function(self,example):
      #Is this a member function?
```

Comment: Yes, "member function" is the C++ name for method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A member function is a function belonging to that specific class. So yes - what you have with "def function(..." is correct.